# What are the security implications if Apache Solr runs without SSL?

Tags: ssl, solr

If I restrict access to Solr with both Apache password protection and by restricting access to the server's own IP, is there any additional security benefit in configuring my search app to send its queries over HTTPS?

I am using an IP Access Handler in jetty.xml to restrict access based on IP.

Comment: What's your setup? Does the communication happen on the internal network or outside over the internet? Is the content assumed to be public knowledge or something that shouldn't be visible if someone suddenly got access to one of the nodes the traffic travels through? This will, in general, come down to the policies of your workplace. In general, Solr is used on internal networks, if you're exposing it to a public endpoint, it should be closed down as much as possible, and I'd strongly suggest using a SSL capable reverse proxy in front (for example nginx) instead of exposing Solr directly.

Comment: @MatsLindh  Thanks.  The communication is internal.  Both the app that sends queries to Solr and the Solr install are on the same server.  There is nothing sensitive in the site content.

Comment: If both server and client is on the same server there shouldn't really be any reason to use SSL. All communication happens over the local interface. I'm pretty sure that other users can't capture localhost traffic without being root (linux) (on Windows capturing localhost is troublesome in itself). There is not really any need for password protection either as long as the server is only binding to localhost (127.0.0.1 etc.), unless you're expecting other users to have direct access to the localhost interface through your or other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Caveats section for [Basic Authentication](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/basic-authentication-plugin.html#enable-basic-authentication):

"Credentials are sent in plain text by default. It’s recommended to use SSL for communication when Basic authentication is enabled, as described in the section Enabling SSL."

Thus, for a secure installation, SSL must be used if Basic authentication is the only way that Solr's admin UI is protected.